# JavaScript 'calculator ' not providing 'running total' when adding last parseFloat

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to construct a basic sales calculator, based on the user's selections. The code below works fine, except for one issue...

With the '+ parseFloat(e)' attribute removed, the user gets a nice, running total as they select or deselect their options. However... when I attempt to add that aspect back into the equation, it will not produce a total until all selections have been made.

Instead... it will only produce '$NaN', until all selections are made.

I would like to be able to achieve the handy 'running total' with the '+ parseFloat(e)' attribute included in the equation. I can't seem to get that to function.

```js
function calcuMath() {
  var z;
  var a = document.getElementById("scoops").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("nuts").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("sprinkles").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("syrup").value;
  var e = document.getElementById("dish").value;
  var sel = document.getElementById("plus");
  var selection = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
  var more = document.getElementById("add");
  if (selection == "add") {
    z = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c) + parseFloat(d) + parseFloat(e);
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "" + z + "";
}
```

```css
.plus {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Ice Cream Calculator</h1>

<p>To calculate the price of your Ice Cream, please make your selections below.</p>

<br>

<select id="scoops" name="scoops" onchange="calcuMath()" required>

  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">How Many Scoops?</option>
  <option value="1">1 Scoop = $1.00</option>
  <option value="2">2 Scoops = $2.00</option>

</select>

<br>
<br>

<p>Toppings: (Optional)</p>

<select id="plus" class="plus">
  <option value="add" id="add">+</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="nuts" name="nuts" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="this.previousSibling.value=1-this.previousSibling.value; 
    calcuMath();">&nbspNuts $1.00

<br>
<br>

<select id="plus" class="plus">
  <option value="add" id="add">+</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="sprinkles" name="sprinkles" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="this.previousSibling.value=1-this.previousSibling.value; 
    calcuMath();">&nbspSprinkles $1.00

<br>
<br>

<select id="plus" class="plus">
  <option value="add" id="add">+</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="syrup" name="syrup" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="this.previousSibling.value=1-this.previousSibling.value; 
    calcuMath();">&nbspSyrup $1.00

<br>
<br>
<br>

<select id="plus" class="plus">
  <option value="add" id="add">+</option>
</select>

<select id="dish" name="dish" onchange="calcuMath()" required>

  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Cup or Cone</option>
  <option value="1">Cup = $1.00</option>
  <option value="2">Cone = $2.00</option>

</select>

<br>
<br>
<br> TOTAL: $
<a id="result"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retain your `parseFloat` (reading up on using `Number()` as
@sorold suggest would also be a good idea) and achieve what you're looking for by giving a default value of '0' to your scoop & cone selection:

```js
function calcuMath() {
  var z;
  var a = document.getElementById("scoops").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("nuts").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("sprinkles").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("syrup").value;
  var e = document.getElementById("dish").value;
  var sel = document.getElementById("plus");
  var selection = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
  var more = document.getElementById("add");
  if (selection == "add") {
    z = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c) + parseFloat(d) + parseFloat(e);
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "" + z + "";
}
```

```css
.plus {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Ice Cream Calculator</h1>

<p>To calculate the price of your Ice Cream, please make your selections below.</p>

<br>

<select id="scoops" name="scoops" onchange="calcuMath()" required>

  <option value='0' selected="true" disabled="disabled">How Many Scoops?</option>
  <option value="1">1 Scoop = $1.00</option>
  <option value="2">2 Scoops = $2.00</option>

</select>

<br>
<br>

<p>Toppings: (Optional)</p>

<select id="plus" class="plus">
  <option value="add" id="add">+</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="nuts" name="nuts" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="this.previousSibling.value=1-this.previousSibling.value; 
    calcuMath();">&nbspNuts $1.00

<br>
<br>

<select id="plus" class="plus">
  <option value="add" id="add">+</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="sprinkles" name="sprinkles" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="this.previousSibling.value=1-this.previousSibling.value; 
    calcuMath();">&nbspSprinkles $1.00

<br>
<br>

<select id="plus" class="plus">
  <option value="add" id="add">+</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="syrup" name="syrup" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="this.previousSibling.value=1-this.previousSibling.value; 
    calcuMath();">&nbspSyrup $1.00

<br>
<br>
<br>

<select id="plus" class="plus">
  <option value="add" id="add">+</option>
</select>

<select id="dish" name="dish" onchange="calcuMath()" required>

  <option value='0' selected="true" disabled="disabled">Cup or Cone</option>
  <option value="1">Cup = $1.00</option>
  <option value="2">Cone = $2.00</option>

</select>

<br>
<br>
<br> TOTAL: $
<a id="result"></a>
```

The reason for your `NaN` error before is that the default options for those two selections had no value, which `parseFloat` evaluates to `undefined`. Hence, when you try to combine all the values into a total, you were actually calculating, for example, `1 + 2 + 1 + undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

ParseFloat will output NaN when you have an empty string. Use Number(x) instead.

Comment: Per Marco, the correction was to simply add a value='0' to the 'selected' options of the two select input fields. Works like a charm now.